# Advanced custom fields - WPML issue

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I have a website with 2 language: dutch (default) and french. I've created an option page with Advanced custom fields. You add upload the website logo and some address information over there. Everything works perfect on my default language "dutch", but the logo doesn't load on the french part of the site.

Inspect element:

```
<img src(unknown) alt="Axces">
```

My html is:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('website_logo', 'option'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: what are the setting for your custom image field inside WPML -> Settings -> Custom Field Translation ?

Answer (score 0):

In Wpml->settings->Post Types Translation, turn on Field Groups(acf-field-group) with 'Translatable - use translation if available or fallback to default language'. This will I think solve your issue.

Comment: I've selected this option, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I've created new option fields and they are available in both languages. But when I create a new image field, that doesn't work in the other language.

Comment: does image field work in main language ? make sure that you had assigned  'Return Value' as 'Image URL'  where you had created a custom field. i.e.in admin go to custom Fields->your field group->your field name->return value -> Image URL

Comment: Plesae refer this I think you will get solution from this link. https://wpml.org/forums/topic/acf-field-type-image-not-showing-on-translated-pages/

Comment: You should have wpml premium plugin for media translation then you have to translate all media and then upload it again, It will definitely  work.

Comment: It's not only with the image. The problem also occurs with the text fields. I don't think that the wpml premium plugin for media translation will do the trick.